# Ubuntu 13.04 Boots into terminal

Tags: boot, 13.04, tty

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04. Since update the system boots in to tty.

Currently the default is kernel 3.8; however using advanced menu entries, the GUI loads successfully using kernel 3.5.

how to make it default?

Any solution to get 3.8 working?

Comment: Have you tried running `startx` on the tty? If that doesn't work, try reinstalling the kernel image.

Comment: yes. how to reinstall kernel image? sorry but a noob in that case

Answer (score 0):

When you log into the GUI (*with kernel version 3.5*), type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, then run:

```
uname -r
```

if the result of this command **contains** the `3.8.something` numbering, edit your question to include its output.

Otherwise run

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.8.* linux-headers-3.8.*
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Restart your computer. Edit your question if you cannot log into the GUI or have found any other problem with this procedure. Otherwise, open a terminal again and run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then restart again and see if it worked.

Comment: this will remove kernel 3.8. How to install again? 

apt-get install will work?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` should install it *if your current version of Ubuntu supports it*. (You usually don't install a kernel, you *upgrade* to a kernel)